# Devexpress, RepositoryItemComboBox with multiple columns like RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to display grid with multiple columns (like in `RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit`) after click on cell in column, but if user don't want to pick item from grid, he can write something else (like in `RepositoryItemComboBox`). How to combine this two features?

```
//user can write, but only one column
RepositoryItemComboBox cbeMaterialy = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
DataTable dt = Getdt();
cbeMaterialy.Items.Clear();

foreach(DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    cbeMaterialy.Items.Add(item);
}

gvView.Columns["ColumnName"].ColumnEdit = cbeMaterialy;



//user cannot write but multiple columns
RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit editor = new RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit();
editor.DataSource = dt;
column.ColumnEdit = editor;
```

//SOLUTION!
I mixed some answer from Devexpress team and came up with this:

```
public class Main()
    {
        //user can choose element from DB or write new value
        RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit riglue = new RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit();
        MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper.SetupGridLookUpEdit(riglue, GetMaterialyDataView(), "Kod", "Kod");
        elementsEditGrid.gvView.Columns[ColumnName].ColumnEdit = riglue;
    }


///////////////////

public class MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper
{
    RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit edit;

    public MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper(RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit edit, ITypedList dataSource, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        this.edit = edit;

        //enable writing into RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit
        edit.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard;

        edit.DataSource = dataSource;
        edit.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        edit.ValueMember = valueMember;
        edit.ProcessNewValue += edit_ProcessNewValue;

        AddExistingValuesToDataSource();
    }

    public static void SetupGridLookUpEdit(RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit edit, ITypedList dataSource, string displayMember, string valueMember) 
    {
        new MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper(edit, dataSource, displayMember, valueMember);
    }

    //Add new values to temporary data source (not to DataBase!)
    void edit_ProcessNewValue(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ProcessNewValueEventArgs e)
    {
        GridLookUpEdit lookUp = sender as GridLookUpEdit;
        RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit ri = lookUp.Properties;
        DataTable dt = (ri.DataSource as DataView).Table;
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[ri.DisplayMember] = e.DisplayValue;
        row[ri.ValueMember] = e.DisplayValue;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        ri.View.RefreshData();
        e.Handled = true;

        //if user wants to add new values to database (data source)
        //INSERT INTO DataSourceTable (ColumnName) VALUES (e.DisplayValue)
    }

    //Adds to temporary data source values already stored in RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit (in case values aren't from DB)
    void ProcessExistingValues(RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit sender, object value)
    {
        RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit ri = sender;
        DataTable dt = (ri.DataSource as DataView).Table;
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[ri.DisplayMember] = value;
        row[ri.ValueMember] = value;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        ri.View.RefreshData();
    }

    private void AddExistingValuesToDataSource()
    {
        //SELECT from DB values that are already in riglue and add them to TEMPORARY DATA SOURCE (in case values aren't from DB)
        //DataView dataView = SELECT ColumnName FROM table WHERE rowID = XXX

        foreach (DataRow row in dataView.AsEnumerable())
        {
            string kod = (string)row["ColumnName"];

            ProcessExistingValues(this.edit, kod);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit.TextEditStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_TextEditStyletopic) property to Standard and you will be able to type. When a user types something different from what is contained in the lookup data source, the [RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit.ProcessNewValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditBase_ProcessNewValuetopic) event will be raised. In the event handler, you can add a new value to the data source to use it further.

Comment: What if I don't want to add new value to data source? Is that possible?

Comment: It's a data-aware control and it works with its data source. So, a record should be in the data source. But, you can follow the https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2297 example to achieve your task. There a wrapper for the real data source is created.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. But what about making "multi column RepositoryItemComboBox"? Isn't that possible?

Comment: ComboBox only supports one column

Answer (score 0):

`RepositoryItemComboBox` doesn't has `DataSourse` property, which allow to bind table with multiple column.

`ComboBoxEdit` Has `DataSourse` property, So you can bnd table with multiple column, OR create multiple column.